# How to run Hello World ASP .NET application using JetBrains Rider on Mac?

Tags: c#, asp.net, jetbrains-ide, rider

How to run Web Application (e.g. Hello World) using JetBrains Rider on Mac?

I picked as a new project ASP .Net web application:
[image]

But configuration seems empty:
[image: .]

And this is output and can not see any web page:
[image]

Comment: do you have the specific requirement to use only asp.net and not asp.net core?

Comment: There's an error at the bottom of your second image about not finding the XSP server, which makes it seem like you might have installed the mono runtime, but not all the dev dependencies.

Comment: Thanks. I am first time setting up on Mac.. How to setup a server etc? Should I use Mono runtime or not? And how to configure all?